# CFSDK payment gateway 'Invalid token sent in request'

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, payment-gateway

I am working on an app in which I need to integrate payment gateway and I am using [Cashfree](https://github.com/cashfree/ios-CFWebSDK) payment gateway `WebView Checkout` option as per the need. It is easy to implement from their [docs](https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/ios/guide/). This is how I initiate SDK:

```
func initiateCFSDK() {
        let cashfreeVC = CFViewController(params: getPaymentParams(), appId: self.appId, env: self.environmentCF, callBack: self)
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cashfreeVC)
        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Payment parameters:

```
func getPaymentParams() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
        return [
            "orderId": self.orderId,
            "tokenData" : self.paymentToken,
            "orderAmount": self.paymentValue,
            "customerName": "name",
            "orderNote": "health prodcuts",
            "orderCurrency": "INR",
            "customerPhone": "9876543210",
            "customerEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
            "notifyUrl": "https://test.gocashfree.com/notify"
        ]
    }
```

From their docs, we need to drag and drop framework to Xcode project and add it to `Embedded Binaries`. The token in generated from the backend using the orderId and need to pass it in payment parameters.

**Problem 1:**
Everytime I Initiate SDK it gives me error: **"Invalid token sent in request"** and prints following result in `delegate` method:

`Finished navigating to url https://test.cashfree.com/billpay/checkout/post/submit
JSON value : {"orderId":"","referenceId":"","orderAmount":"","txMsg":"Invalid token sent in request","txTime":"","txStatus":"FAILED","paymentMode":"","signature":""}`

Following is the screenshot for the reference.

[image]

**Problem 2:**
Since I present the SDK by embedding inside a UINavigationController, when I press back button it can't dismiss itself.

I am banging my head from many weeks for the error (Invalid token) I can't resolve. So anyone here tried it and please take a look what is wrong? Looking forward for the solutions from SO.

P.S: I tried contacting their tech support and everytime they just sent link to their docs.

Comment: Are you sure about order info used to generate the token is matched with request with sdk ? , I think token doesn't matches or wrong order_id passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared demo project with Cash Free SDK, Using Xcode 11.0

**Step 1**

**To Generate the token , I have used in postman**

https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/cftoken/order

with parameters

```
{
"orderId":"ORD123456",
"orderAmount":"30",
"orderCurrency":"INR"
}
```

with following headers

```
Content-Type:application/json
X-Client-Id:XXXXXXX
X-Client-Secret:XXXXXX
```

**Step 2**

Now In code

```
func initiateCFSDK() {
    let cashfreeVC = CFViewController(params: getPaymentParams(), appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx", env: "TEST", callBack: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cashfreeVC, animated: true)
 }
       func getPaymentParams() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
           return [
               "orderId": "ORD123456",
               "tokenData" : "<<TOKEN FROM POSTMAN REQUEST>>",
               "orderAmount": "30",
               "customerName": "name",
               "orderNote": "health prodcuts",
               "orderCurrency": "INR",
               "customerPhone": "9876543210",
               "customerEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
               "notifyUrl": "https://test.gocashfree.com/notify"
           ]
       }
```

Here Nothing changed just used *TEST*  environment and passed the  appid and token

Notes:

1. make sure you are using TEST environment URL to generate token with TEST environment client id and client secret
2. also check **notifyUrl**
3. Order ID should be same
4. make sure you are not using old or expired tokens

Problem 2 : Don't bother to present , just push this controller :)

Cheers !! :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking out time, I will give it a shot and let you know.